# Performance Tuning In Plsql Function Query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, query-performance

I have plsql  function. And this function has query like as below:

```
select  colum_name 
from table_name 
where  filter_coloumn_name in ( select filter_coloumn_name from table_name_2);
```

My function is used by other query to return value from query. This query which use this function take more time. Even the site (front screen) down. Because    table_name_2 has three million record. So that i must use some performance tuning method in my function. I change my function query like as below:

```
cursor my_cursor IS  
  select filter_coloumn_name from table_name_2;

TYPE cursor_array_type IS TABLE OF my_cursor%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 
m    cursor_array_type;

TYPE cursor_table_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
cursor_table_object cursor_table_type; 

fetch_size NUMBER := 5000;
index_var number;

begin 
index_var := 1; 

open my_cursor; 
    loop
      FETCH my_cursor BULK COLLECT
        into m LIMIT fetch_size;
      exit when my_cursor %notfound; 

     for i in 1 .. m.count loop       
        cursor_table_object (index_var) := m(i).filter_coloumn_name;     
       index_var := index_var + 1;
     end loop;
    end loop;
  Close my_cursor; 

   select  colum_name 
    from table_name 
    where  filter_coloumn_name in (cursor_table_object);
```

> select  colum_name 
>           from table_name 
>           where  filter_coloumn_name in (cursor_table_object);

Namely, i want fetch all values at one time, and then i want use this table object like as above. But i can't use table object with in condition expression in sql query.

I take `PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type` error.

I want to use this table object like as below:

```
select  colum_name 
from table_name 
where  filter_coloumn_name in ('bla', 'bla bla', 'bla bla bla');
```

Should i convert table object to the array ?

Comment: How much record in table_name table ?

Comment: it has three million record too.

Comment: Do you need to return all the record at once ? Could you please explain the purpose of this function ? Because returning 3 million record is very high.

Comment: It has some condition so record count will be reduced. But i  must use  ready, fetched data (array, table) after  in condition.

Comment: Instead of function use View and use inner join instead of sub query. Please share the condition information

Comment: Query is slow too with big data. I want to fetch data once. And then i will use data (ready, fetched data) in condition. In this way i think data is fetched more fastly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion, based on what you've said so far: how about using a **table function**? It makes it possible to use something like statement you wanted to use, i.e.

```
select colum_name from table_name where filter_coloumn_name in (cursor_table_object);
```

but which returns

> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

---

Here's an example based on Scott's schema. Have a look:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys.odcinumberlist
  3  is
  4    -- Cursor's SELECT should contain your 3-million-rows table
  5    cursor cur_r is select deptno from dept where deptno < 30;
  6    l_ret sys.odcinumberlist;
  7  begin
  8    open cur_r;
  9    fetch cur_r bulk collect into l_ret;
 10    close cur_r;
 11    return l_ret;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> -- How to use it?
SQL> select e.ename
  2  from emp e join table(f_test) x on x.column_value = e.deptno;

ENAME
----------
MILLER
KING
CLARK
ADAMS
SCOTT
FORD
JONES
SMITH

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 'sys.odcinumberlist' type ?

Comment: It is built-in collection type for numeric values (so that I wouldn't have to declare my own type for this purpose).

Answer (score 0):

You must use exists instead of in, also table_name_2 must have index over filter_coloumn_name field.
Using cursor only what you get is full access to a big table.